# question about locked file

Tags: linux

I have a file which some program locked and after that the program quit. Now no program can lock this file.
This file is located on NFS share on server A, and I'm locking it from server B.
I used fuser and lsof utilities on server A to check which process holds the lock, but the output was empty in both cases.
The lock is done using perl script, like in this code example:

my $lockmask = pack('s s l l s', &F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0);
fcntl(LOCKFILE, &F_SETLK, $lockmask)

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Restart the nfslock service.

Answer (score 0):

The nfslock service is running on your local host, not the server.  When it restarts, it will notify the central lock daemon that "Hey!  I'm new around here.  I have no locks at this time."  The central lock daemon will then review its checklist of acquired locks, notice that your local host *used* to have some, but since it just heard that it doesn't have any, it will be allowed to release the locks since they are now stale.

There is probably a start up script specifically for nfslock.  For example, under RedHat, you may be able to call `service nfslock restart`.  Under other operating systems or OS flavors, it may be a script called  `/etc/rc.d/nfslock` and you will have to run it twice - once with the `stop` parameter and once with the `start` parameter. 
Once you have restarted the lock manager, check to see that it started correctly with `rpcinfo -p` and look for at least one line with `nlockmgr` in the service column.  A quick list of important NFS commands is at [linuxconfig.org](http://www.linuxconfig.org/HowTo_configure_NFS).

If this is a production system, you should notify your users.  You should also stop doing development on the host if it is a production system lest you repeat this situation and cause an outage.

By the way, there is a much more readable way to get locks over NFS in Perl. [File::NFSLock](http://search.cpan.org/~bbb/File-NFSLock-1.20/lib/File/NFSLock.pm) is clear, concise, and probably better tested than your code.  No offense.  It will make much more sense to yourself and others when you have to come back to this code.  Also, you should assume that locking might not be working on your shared filesystem at the moment.  In such a case, you should deal with the failure gracefully and then properly log the fault.  Do **not** assume that locking is working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can't restart the nfslock service because then all the locks would be gone and it may cause unexpected problems in my other applications. Do you have an idea how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Alas, I don't know. Opinions on NFSv3 have led me to believe that locking is not rock solid.  I haven't read anything that convinces me that it is any better under NFSv4, but I don't know for sure.  All I can suggest at this time is that you develop a test bed that exercises various failure scenarios and to see that your recovery procedures are both correct and sufficient.